# Wait for Observable to Complete Inside of Array.Map

Tags: rxjs, observable, nestjs

I have an array of objects in which one of the keys includes a customer id.

```
const customerArray = [{ customerId: 123, ...}, { customerId: 456, ...}];
```

I want to iterate through this array and make an api call to get further details about this customer from a separate endpoint.

```
const mapped = customerArray
  .map(customer => ({
    customerId: customer.customerId,
    rating: this.productService(customer.customerId)
               .pipe(map(rating => rating))}));
```

My expectation is that I would then have an array that includes an object with the following shape:

```
{
  customerId: number,
  rating: number
}
```

Instead, I end up with:

```
{
  customerId: number,
  rating: Observable
}
```

My `productService` call returns on observable and is used elsewhere in the app successfully. I need to have my `map` wait for the call to complete on the rating key before mapping to the next item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you have to iterate through an array, make an http request to an endpoint for each element of the array, and fill each element of the array with the data returned by the endpoint.
So, if this is the case, you may try `mergeMap` like this

```
const myObs = from(customerArray).pipe(
  mergeMap(customer => {
    return this.productService(customer.customerId).pipe(
      map(rating => ({customerId: customer.customerId, rating}))
    )
  })
)
```

If you subscribe to `myObs` you should get a stream of objects in the shape you are looking for, i.e.

```
{
  customerId: number,
  rating: number
}
```

`mergeMap`, previously known as `flatMap`, allows you to flatten a stream of Observables. In other words, if you iterate through an array to generate an array of Observables, which should be your case, `mergeMap` allows you to extract the values inside the Observables generated.

Comment: Ah! Much better than my solution with converting to a promise! I think the only thing would be adding the `combineAll()` at the end to keep it as a single emitted array.

Comment: So I can see the result of the subscription is in fact the right shape, but I am having an issue now in which I cannot take this value and put it into my API response inside of NestJS. This is a bit of a separate question than what it being asked here, but is there a way to convert this from an observable to an array that I can use to return an array back to the caller of this function? I tried adding @JayMcDoniel combineAll() but this did not resolve it

Comment: Actually, change the `combineAll()` to a `toArray()` due to the observable typing and it would give the correct output

Answer (score 0):

[I got a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xy38wn?file=index.ts) setup that shows a way you can manage it, but for the sake of keeping it always available

```js
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, mergeMap, combineAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

const custArray = [{customerId: 1}, {customerId: 2}, {customerId: 3}];

function mapSomeStuff(id: number): Observable<number> {
  return of(id * id);
}

function doProductStuff(custArr: Array<{customerId: number}>): Observable<Array<{ customerId: number, rating: number}>> {
  return from(custArray)
    .pipe(
      map(async (cust) => ({
        customerId: cust.customerId,
        rating: await mapSomeStuff(cust.customerId).toPromise()
    })),
    combineAll()
  );
}

doProductStuff(custArray).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

This breaks up the array and creates an observable for each value in the array, runs the service, converts the observable to a promise and gets the final value of it, then combines all of the observables into a single observable with an array of values being the final out. You can check the output and see `[Object, Object, Object]` and check to see that the `customerId` and `rating` are available on each `Object`.